# has/had a Boston postmark

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

If you have just received a letter, do you say:

> It **has** a Boston postmark.

Or:

> It **had** a Boston postmark.

The act of postmarking the letter took place in the past, but it carries the postmark now. Which tense should be used?

Comment: It *has* a postmark, because it *was postmarked* two days ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either can be used in various situations.  It definitely **has** a Boston postmark right now, so the present tense can be used.  If you look at the envelope, and then walk into the next room and talk about it there, you could say that it **had** a Boston postmark (when you looked at it).  It still **has** the postmark, but it **had** it too.

It would be strange, and likely considered incorrect to say "It **had** a Boston postmark" while you are looking at it, right now.